# Drag and drop by ng2-Dragula library

Tags: angular, ng2-dragula

I need to find out a new item position after it has been moved.

```
<div *ngFor="let group of groups; let index = index"
                 [dragulaItem]="group">
  group.name
</div>


dragulaService.drop
  .subscribe((dragulaBag) => {
    console.dir(dragulaBag[1].dragulaItem);
  });
```

Returns the item with the old position

How to get the item and its new position after dragging?

Comment: Do you have any fiddle for this? That might help

Answer (score 0):

Is answer to my question

const groupId: number = dragulaBag[2].dragulaItem.id;
const newPosition: number = 
  this.groups.indexOf(dragulaBag[4].dragulaItem) + 1;